# How to fix Nginx 502 Bad Gateway? -- Django Google App Deployment

Tags: django, nginx, google-app-engine, web-deployment, gunicorn

Overview: After successfully completing [this google app deployment documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) I run the last code within the documentation. -- `$ gcloud app deploy` -- After a few minutes waiting for the app to deploy I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p024.png) "502 badgateway nginx". Im currently on a MacBook Pro (Big Sur). Does anyone have a suggestion on how this problem may be resolved?

Here is my settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for HealthHelper_site project.
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.1.
For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/
For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

#This is the original settings.py that was swapped with one to work and connect with
#Google's console... this is the orignal copy of the django settings.py file

from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'main.apps.MainConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'HealthHelper_site.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
'DIRS': [],
'APP_DIRS': True,
'OPTIONS': {
'context_processors': [
'django.template.context_processors.debug',
'django.template.context_processors.request',
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
],
},
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'HealthHelper_site.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
}
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
'NAME':
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=
Here is my requirements.txt below:

```
Django==3.2.4
django-environ==0.4.5
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
google-cloud-secret-manager==2.5.0
PyMySQL==1.0.2
mysqlclient==1.4.1
```

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=
If any other information needed please let me know!

Comment: Please add more information about the deployment, like this other [post with a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67385762/getting-502-bad-gateway-nginx-while-accessing-java-application-deployed-on-kub).

Comment: You should check the Stackdriver Logs to know the reason of your error. Most probably it would be a code error. Check [this documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-application-logs#viewing_logs) as a reference.